# What is the general process for writing errata pages to sefarim?

Tags: jewish-books, mistakes, safrus, publications, intellectual-property

Not sure if this question is on topic but here goes.

### Background

There is a STA"M textbook called מאיר עיני סופרים which summarizes the rulings of the major sources on hilchos STA"M for contemporary ashkenazim. The book was released in one edition and is now out of print but it is still a well-used reference despite many citation errors and typos. I am thinking about writing en errata page.

### Questions

- What would the best way to publish such a project? Options include web, pdf available on request, print booklet, or something I haven't thought of.
- Would such an errata page require permission from the author's estate (rendering the idea DOA for now)?
- Does anyone here have experience with this sort of endeavor in either the Jewish or general academic publishing industry?

Comment: I can't imagine why you would need permission to publish your own errata sheet, but [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL).

Comment: Perhaps the authors family is interested in reprinting their relatives work in a new and improved edition. Many times they will even sponsor such an endeavor, or direct you to such sponsors.